# TOCO unable to convert unsupported operation using --allow_custom_ops

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, toco

I am trying to convert mobilenet_v2 model trained on pascal voc dataset (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md).

I want to infer with 1024x1024 resolution therefore I exported model with following commands.

```
 python export_model.py \
--checkpoint_path model/model.ckpt-30000 \
--export_path ./frozen_inference_graph.pb \
--model_variant="mobilenet_v2" \
--num_classes=21 \
--crop_size=1024 \
--crop_size=1024 \
--inference_scales=1.0
```

And then I convert model to tflite using toco command.

```
toco --graph_def_file=/home/abdullah/models-master/research   /frozen_casted.pb --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF                                                         

--output_format=TFLITE  

--output_file=deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_trainval.tflite   
--inference_type=FLOAT --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8
--input_arrays=ImageTensor 
--output_arrays=SemanticPredictions
--input_shapes=1,1024,1024,3 --default_ranges_min=0 
--default_ranges_max=255 --allow_custom_ops  
--std_dev_values=128 --mean_values=1
```

And then model is converted to tflite without errors :

```
    2019-07-16 00:28:18.188009: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1171] Converting unsupported operation: Equal
2019-07-16 00:28:18.188052: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1171] Converting unsupported operation: Equal
2019-07-16 00:28:18.188067: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1171] Converting unsupported operation: LogicalOr
2019-07-16 00:28:18.188093: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1171] Converting unsupported operation: Unpack
2019-07-16 00:28:18.188134: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1171] Converting unsupported operation: LogicalAnd
2019-07-16 00:28:18.192256: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1171] Converting unsupported operation: ResizeNearestNeighbor
2019-07-16 00:28:18.203603: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 813 operators, 1237 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-07-16 00:28:18.232795: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 801 operators, 1215 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-07-16 00:28:18.269909: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 801 operators, 1215 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-07-16 00:28:18.293777: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After general graph transformations pass 1: 132 operators, 325 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-07-16 00:28:18.296414: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before dequantization graph transformations: 132 operators, 325 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-07-16 00:28:18.298905: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/allocate_transient_arrays.cc:311] Total transient array allocated size: 28311552 bytes, theoretical optimal value: 25165824 bytes.
2019-07-16 00:28:18.299732: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tflite/operator.cc:661] Ignoring unsupported attribute type with key '_output_shapes'
2019-07-16 00:28:18.299743: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tflite/operator.cc:661] Ignoring unsupported attribute type with key 'T'
2019-07-16 00:28:18.299946: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tflite/operator.cc:661] Ignoring unsupported attribute type with key 'T'
2019-07-16 00:28:18.299956: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tflite/operator.cc:661] Ignoring unsupported attribute type with key '_output_shapes'
```

But when I run the model on tflite it gives the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Cannot create interpreter: Didn't find custom op for name 'ExpandDims' with version 1
>       Registration failed.

For conversion I used tensorflow **tensorflow=='1.6.0-rc1'**

And tflite implementation in build.gradle is **implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'**

I don't know where I am failing, please help me.

Comment: ```--allow_custom_ops``` was added in TF 1.10
See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_reference.md#transformation-flags

Comment: But tf1.10 is very old and can not convert model to tflite "NodeDef mentions attr 'Truncate' not in Op<name=Cast; signature=x:SrcT -> y:DstT; attr=SrcT:type; attr=DstT:type>; NodeDef: Cast = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_UINT8, Truncate=false, _output_shapes=[[?,?,3]]](Squeeze). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
"

Comment: I meant its available in TF 1.10 and higher. I see you are using TF 1.6 which is way older. I would recommend using tf-nightly for converting models into tf-lite.

Comment: ExpandDims is now supported as a proper builtin op for TensorFlow Lite. I would update your TensorFlow version (used to convert the model) to at least 1.14.0.